# VBA skipping code directly after submitting form in IE

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel, web-scraping

Currently I have 2 pieces of code that work separately, but when used together they don't work properly.

The first code asks the user to input information which is stored. It then navigates to the correct webpage where it uses the stored user input information to navigate via filling and submitting a form. It arrives at the correct place.

The second code uses a specific URL via `ie.navigate "insert url here"` to navigate to the same place as the first code. It then scrapes URL data and stores it in a newly created sheet. It does this correctly.

When merging them I replace the navigation segment from the second code with the first code, but then it only stores the first 5 of 60 URLs as if it hadn't fully loaded the page before scraping data. It seems to skip the code directly after `ie.document.forms(0).submit` which is supposed to wait for the page to load before moving on to the scraping..

extra info: the button wasn't defined so I cannot just click it so I had to use `ie.document.forms(0).submit`

Summary of what I want the code to do:

```
 request user input
    store user input
    open ie
    navigate to page
    enter user input into search field
    select correct search category from listbox
    submit form
  'problem happens here
    scrape url data
    store url data in specific excel worksheet
```

The merged code:

```
    Sub extractTablesData()

                 Dim ie As Object, obj As Object
                 Dim Var_input As String
                 Dim elemCollection As Object
                 Dim html As HTMLDocument
                 Dim Link As Object
                 Dim erow As Long


                ' create new sheet to store info
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HL").Delete
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "HL"
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True

                 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

                 Var_input = InputBox("Enter info")

                 With ie

                 .Visible = True
                 .navigate ("URL to the webpage")

                 While ie.readyState <> 4
                 DoEvents
                 Wend

                'Input Term 1 into input box
                ie.document.getElementById("trm1").Value = Var_input


                'accessing the Field 1 ListBox
                For Each obj In ie.document.all.Item("FIELD1").Options

                        If obj.Value = "value in listbox" Then

                            obj.Selected = True

                        End If

                    Next obj

                ' button undefined - using this to submit form
                ie.document.forms(0).submit
'----------------------------------------------------------------                 
        'seems to skip this part all together when merged           

        'Wait until IE is done loading page
        Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

        Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to website…"
        DoEvents
        Loop

'----------------------------------------------------------------        
        Set html = ie.document
        Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

        For Each Link In ElementCol
        erow = Worksheets("HL").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        Cells(erow, 1).Value = Link
        Cells(erow, 1).Columns.AutoFit
        Next


        Application.StatusBar = “”
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

               End With
            End Sub
```

I've been stuck for quite some time on this and haven't found any solutions on my own so I'm reaching out. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a completely different method. I used a query table with strings to go where I wanted.

```
 Sub ExtractTableData()
    Dim This_input As String
    Const prefix As String = "Beginning of url"
    Const postfix As String = "end of url"

    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HL").Delete
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "HL"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    This_input = InputBox("enter key info to go to specific url")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Set qt = ws.QueryTables.Add( _
    Connection:="URL;" & prefix & This_input & postfix, _
    Destination:=Worksheets("HL").Range("A1"))

    qt.RefreshOnFileOpen = True
    qt.WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
'qt.webtables is key to getting the specific table on the page     
    qt.WebTables = 2

    qt.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False



    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you think the website might not be fully loaded. This is a common problem because of the more dynamic elements on a webpage. The easiest way to handle this is to insert the line:

```
Application.Wait Now + Timevalue("00:00:02")
```

This will force the code to pause for an additional 2 seconds. Insert this line below the code which waits for the page to load and this will give Internet Explorer a chance to catch back up. Depending on the website and the reliability of your connection to it I recommend adjusting this value anywhere up to about 5 seconds.

Most websites seem to require additional waiting like this, so handy code to remember when things don't work as expected. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. With that piece of code it waited perfectly, but the code still didn't grab the all of the links. Since it turns out that that isn't the underlying problem it's time to switch gears. Looking at the source code from the web page it seems to be grabbing the links from the first or last table (both contain the same information), but not from the second and the second table is where the data I'm after lies.